# Symfony1.4 admin generator custom edit and delete actions

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, admin, generator

I want to add custom edit & delete actions in Symfony1.4 Admin generator.

Steps I have done:

1. Created a custom theme for admin.
2. Mentioned `theme: mythemename` in admin module's `generator.yml`
3. In theme template `_list_td_actions` modified as per my customization.

But here I am not able to edit `linkToEdit` & `linkToDelete` functions return value.
Can I override `sfModelGeneratorHelper.class.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom file, like [this one](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/admin/template/lib/helper.php) in this location: `data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/mythemename/template/lib/helper.php`

Here is an example where I override the `linkToEdit`:

```
[?php

/**
 * <?php echo $this->getModuleName() ?> module configuration.
 *
 * @package    ##PROJECT_NAME##
 * @subpackage <?php echo $this->getModuleName()."\n" ?>
 * @author     ##AUTHOR_NAME##
 * @version    SVN: $Id$
 */
abstract class Base<?php echo ucfirst($this->getModuleName()) ?>GeneratorHelper extends sfModelGeneratorHelper
{
  public function getUrlForAction($action)
  {
    return 'list' == $action ? '<?php echo $this->params['route_prefix'] ?>' : '<?php echo $this->params['route_prefix'] ?>_'.$action;
  }

  public function linkToEdit($object, $params)
  {
    return '<li>'.link_to(' ', $this->getUrlForAction('edit'), $object, array('class' => 'box editer', 'title' => 'Editer')).'</li>';
  }
}
```